# Getaroom API: Get list of hotels by destination search

Tags: php, xml, api

**Get the list of hotels from the getaroom api according to destination search.**

This url generates xml file for getting available hotels:
But this API is not the best API optimized for performance as said by the support team:

```
$getaroom_url =  "https://book.getaroom.com/searches/hotel_availability.xml?";
$getaroom_url .= "destination=$city%2C%20$cntry";
$getaroom_url .= "&rinfo=$room_array_string";
$getaroom_url .= "&check_in=$check_in";
$getaroom_url .= "&check_out=$check_out";
$getaroom_url .= "&transaction_id=1234";
$getaroom_url .= "&cancellation_rules=1";
$getaroom_url .= "&api_key=$api_key&auth_token=$auth_token";
```

Therefore we can't use this code for getting the list of hotels.

This is another api to get list of hotels in xml and csv:

**xml format**:
 https://book.getaroom.com/api/properties.xml?api_key=axyzefg****ggggg&auth_token=abcdef****ggggggg

**csv format**:
 https://book.getaroom.com/api/properties.csv?api_key=axyzefg****ggggg&auth_token=abcdef****ggggggg

To do a destination search in Las Vegas, you must pull all uuids that are in Las Vegas and surrounding areas, then do a multi property request.
When uuid is found, then hit another api for that given below:

https://availability.getaroom.com/api/1.1/properties/c1b93287-6260-5c23-8a74-66efa541a5b2/room_availability?rinfo=[[18,18]]&check_in=6/15/2015&check_out=6/17/2015&transaction_id=1234&cancellation_rules=1&api_key=*************&auth_token=*****************

So this is long process to get the availability of the hotel.
Problem is that how to get all the hotel list according to the destination and check-in and check-out in one request. Is there any other api for getaroom through which we can get hotel list by checkin,checkout,destination parameters like in ***Expedia***.
*Thank you in advance*

Comment: Asking about a proprietary web-service doesn't make really sense on Stackoverflow as this question can be only answered by those developers who have full access to the API and can change it. One thing you should do with your question is to ask the question as well the API support team of getaroom.com and report back about their feedback here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On their home page, there is a form to find a hotel.  The first field in the form is "Destination" and that is also the first field in your XML example. I tested their web form with only the destination, check-in and check-out dates, and it returned a list of hotels in a single request.  So this information is available via the GET request on the WWW.  Here is the URL that the form generated:

http://www.getaroom.com/searches/show?amenities[]=&button=&check_in=05%2F13%2F2015&check_out=05%2F14%2F2015&destination=Baltimore&lucky=true&m=127&page=1&property_name=&rinfo=[[18]]&sort_order=position&total_nights=&utf8=%E2%9C%93

I copied and pasted this URL into another browser and it worked fine.  So it is clear that the data you want is available with a straightforward GET request.  Maybe the authors of the API can give you access to the raw information so you would not have to write a scraper script :-)